How to fix "Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version!"?
When I upload to on google play console then got error like this

Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder, from August 31, 2024, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to avoid app crashes.

I tried everything I know but couldn't resolve this issue.
Here is my build.gralde code:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
       
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/NOTICE.md', 'META-INF/LICENSE.md']
        }
    }
    lint {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds true
    }
    namespace 'com.darsenizami.ahyaululoom'
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // AndroidX dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'

    // Firebase Messaging inappmessaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:21.0.0'

    // Firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0'

    // Firebase dependencies with BOM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // Firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'

    // Test dependencies
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'

    // External libraries
    implementation 'com.github.mjn1369:prettydialog:1.0.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0'
    implementation 'com.github.SanojPunchihewa:InAppUpdater:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'

    // Play Core library
    //noinspection RiskyLibrary
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
}


Did you try changing that last line, like it said you should?

But from this question you suggest we cannot find regulations can you help

@SehrMubeen - You need to remove the last line that references your play core version as a dependency and depending on what you do inside of your application, import one of the four libraries play core has been separated into. I wrote an article about how to do this, which can be found here.

I remove this line but after when I upload to play store then get error.  Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder, from August 31, 2024, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to avoid app crashes.
